# What does -lfoo link with if both libfoo.a and libfoo.so are on the library path?

Tags: gcc

Using gcc and gnu ld, I am compiling a binary (a shared object in this case) that depends on a library, let's say libfoo. libfoo comes as both .a and .so files, in the same directory.

Can I know which is being used, the static or the dynamic?

Comment: As far as I know, the GNU toolchain defaults to dynamic linkage if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `ld` on my Linux (Ubuntu 12.10 box) will load the `.so` file first.

From `man ld`:

> ```
>    -l namespec
>    --library=namespec
>        Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
>        files to link.  This option may be used any number of times.  If
>        namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path
>        for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library
>        path for a file called libnamespec.a.
>
>        On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>        files other than libnamespec.a.  Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>        systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>        libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a.  (By
>        convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.)  Note
>        that this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always
>        specifies a file called filename.
> ```

Comment: Perfect reference. The gcc -l docs only talk about .a files, silly of me not to think to check the ld man page.

Answer (score 2):

gcc (and ld, which it's really running behind the scenes) default to dynamic linking if it's available.  You can check the output binary to see which it did, if you want.

If you want to force it to use the static library, you can use the `-static` [link option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options).